# Manejo de carpetas

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en la programación y estoy haciendo un proyecto en el cual quiero crear, abrir y borrar carpetas, pero no encuentro como puedo abrirla.

Utilizo la libreria `java.io.File`. Intente con esto:

```
public void crearCarpeta()                                                  //crea una carpeta(que va a guardar datos de una empresa en especifico)
{
    String direccion = null;
    String nombre = null;
    direccion = "C:\\Users\\MyZ\\Desktop\\respaldo programa java\\Empresas";    //direccion de donde crea la carpeta
    nombre = textBoxNombreEmpresa.getText();                                //obtiene el nombre de la carpeta
    File carpeta = new File(direccion, nombre);
    carpeta.mkdir();  //creo la carpeta
    carpeta.
}
```

Al final donde pone carpeta. Pensé que podría poner algo como `carpeta.open`, pero no encuentro nada con lo que pueda abrirlo.

Comment: Hola Javier. Solo para evitar confusión, Netbeans no es un lenguaje de programación, es simplemente el programa que te permite escribir código en Java. Java es el lenguaje de programación.

Answer (score 2):

Para esta finalidad podría emplear la clase [Desktop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) *(JDK 6+)* , la cuál permite que la aplicación inicie aplicaciones asociadas registradas como *(abrir el navegador , clientes de correo,carpetas)*  , antes de acceder al método [Open](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)) se debe obtener la instancia del contexto actual mediante el método.
[getDesktop()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#getDesktop())

```
String direccion = null;
String nombre = null;
//direccion de donde crea la carpeta
direccion = "C:\\Users\\MyZ\\Desktop\\respaldo programa java\\Empresas";    
nombre = textBoxNombreEmpresa.getText();   //obbtiene el nombre de la carpeta
File carpeta = new File(direccion, nombre);
carpeta.mkdir();  //creo la carpeta
Desktop.getDesktop().open(carpeta);
```

Otra opción sería *(entorno windows)* , ejecutar el `explorer.exe` que se conoce en `windows`,  añadiéndole la ruta `getAbsolutePath`

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer " + carpeta.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta

Comment: @Javier si mi respuesta resolvió su problema , puede marcarla como aceptada. Saludos.